# Unity public fields visible in inspector overlap eachother

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a strage bug in the unity inspector where the public fields overlap eachother. I need to mention i am running unity 2021.1.3f and I haven't done any custom editor scripting. There are just a bunch of public variables and lists in code that overlap eachother. If you need anymore info please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Unity Version Which has **(LTS)**.It will stop this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `[NonReorderable]` attribute on the List/Array in the C# editor. Worked for me as i bumped to this issue.